# Absolute positions is not setting?

Tags: css

I have problem that I am using *after* property for making an arrow for tooltip. When I set its(arrow) position absolute its position changes according to the position of body  **not main div**. For example when I set position of arrow to left:100% it goes to the left side of body, it creates problem for me.
When I set its position relative to left:100% it goes to the left of main div but loses its actual shape
**Problem:** How should I set the **position** of arrow that it remains in its actual shape and its position sets to the left side of main div?
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ToolTip</title>
<style>
    #mainDiv{
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid pink;
        background:pink;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: 15em;
    }

    #mainDiv:after{
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        border-top: 10px solid green;
        border-right: 10px solid blueviolet;
        border-bottom: 10px solid yellow;
        border-left: 10px solid red;
        width:0px;
        height: 0px;
        left: 98%;
        top: 50%;

        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv">

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `#mainDiv { position: relative; }` should fix it

Comment: Try setting a `position: relative` to your #mainDiv. Absolute positioning works with the nearest parent container that has a position set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add `position:relative;` to `#mainDiv` and `position:absolute;` to `#mainDiv:after`.